# @WithMockUser and kotlin test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, kotlintest

I'm a big fan of Kotlintest syntax and I'd like to know if it's possible to make it work with WebMvcTest. More particularly, I don't manage to annotate the test methods with @WithMockUser.

Does somebody know if it's feasible?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that is currently built into KotlinTest but there is a Spring module, so it should be fairly easy to create another extension that provides this.

This is the source for the spring module.
https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/tree/master/kotlintest-samples/kotlintest-samples-spring